# CakePHP - Unit testing validation not called

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp

I'm doing some unit testing but having issues with Model validation not getting called.

Here is what I have in the Fixture.

```
<?php
    class ItemFixture extends CakeTestFixture {
    var $name = 'Item';
    var $import = array(
            'model' => 'Item',
            'table' => 'items'
    );

    var $records = array(array(
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'Title2',
            'year' => '1992'
            ),array(
            'id' => 2,
            'title' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
            'year' => '1995'
            ));
    }
```

?>

Here is what I have in the model unit test

```
    <?php

    App::import('Model', 'Item');

    class ItemTest extends Item {
            var $name = 'ItemTest';
            var $useTable = 'items';
            var $useDbConfig = 'test';
    }

    class ItemTestCase extends CakeTestCase {
            var $fixtures = array('app.item');

            function startTest() {
                    $this->ItemTest =& ClassRegistry::init('ItemTest');
            }

            function testAdd() {
                    $data = array(
                    'ItemTest' => array(
                    'title' => 'Best article Evar!'
                    )
                    );

                    $result = $this->ItemTest->saveAll($data);
            }

            function endTest() {

    }
```

}

?>

And here is the validation that I have in the actual Model.

```
    'year' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'numeric',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => 'Numbers only'
    ),
    'minLength' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', 4),
            'message' => 'Year in YYYY format'
    ),
    'maxLength' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 4),
            'message' => 'Year in YYYY format'
    )
```

See, in testAdd, I'm not passing year which is not supposed to be empty, but it actually passed. Why isn't the validation getting called?

Thank you,

Tee

Answer (score 2):

`allowEmpty` only works if the data contains the specified field, in your case `year`. To make the validation fail you either have to add `'year' => ''` to your `$data` array in `testAdd` or add `'required' => true` to your validation rule to enforce there is a `year` field in the data.

See also http://book.cakephp.org/view/1148/allowEmpty